# Crystal report in C # need log on

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I wrote the following in Visual Studio 2010:

```
    label2.Text = Convert.ToString(BAssistencia.nroo);
    ReportDocument oRep = new ReportDocument();
    ParameterField campo = new ParameterField();
    ParameterFields campo2 = new ParameterFields();
    ParameterDiscreteValue Pdv = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

    campo.Name = "@pedido";
    Pdv.Value = label2.Text;
    campo.CurrentValues.Add(Pdv);
    campo2.Add(campo);
    crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = campo2;
    oRep.Load("C:/Relatorios/CrystalReport3.rpt");
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oRep;
    oRep.SetDatabaseLogon("sa","password","server","database");
```

The report opens fine on the computer with Visual Studio, but when I deploy, the application asks for the log again and again. What am I Doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code

```
ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
        rpt.Load(@"C:\CrystalReport1.rpt");

        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "SERVERNAME";
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DATABASENAME";
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = "USERNAME";
        crConnectionInfo.Password = "PASSWORD";
        crConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;

        TableLogOnInfos crTableLogonInfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crTableLogonInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        Tables CrTables;
        CrTables = rpt.Database.Tables;

        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crTable in CrTables)
        {
            crTableLogonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
            crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo);
        }
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: change it as per requirement it is working and will also work for you

Comment: thanks but from where come crTable??? i dont see where crtable is created. Crtables = rpt.database.tables exist but crtable?? I think this code may work .

Comment: @alejandro crTable is datatable of CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table. just like foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows) which you often used in c#. you may use anyother name for crTable which you like. i have try this code and it is working fine.

Comment: Asif the code you have show works perfect in Windows 7, when i go to run on win XP again ask for logon.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for solving this problem.

1. Use a windows user account for accessing database
   [More details are here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sv/vscrystalreports/thread/6aee318c-e834-44ce-b217-f032a00784e8)
2. Apply credentials to main reports and all subreports dynamically

[Application runs slow when DB logging info is applied to each Crystal Reports Sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105318/application-runs-slow-when-db-logging-info-is-applied-to-each-crystal-reports-se)

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/214322/c-crystal-reports-changing-database-and-server-name