# SSIS - "not enough storage is available to complete this operation" with wide table OLEDB destination

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm developing an SSIS package, SQL server to SQL server, this is a fairly standard package not much going on, and it is use for many other tables in the system.

When I add in a wider table, 201 columns in this case, when attempting to perform the mappings in the OLEDB destination it just returns an error - "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation".

This doesn't appear related to any local storage issues, there's plenty of hard drive space and RAM available, certainly a lot more than the table takes up (orders of magnitude more).

Any ideas what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Worth pointing out, this only occurs when "Fast load" is used on the destination. Without that it allows the mapping fine and runs fine, albeit quite a lot slower.

Comment: Does these solutions help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626056/not-enough-storage-is-available-to-complete-this-operation

Comment: It's not a memory issue, like I mentioned, it works if fast load is disabled, so it can handle the volume, it's just bugging out with that option.